# Android WorkManager - Return value

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I've a task in doWork() and i need to wait before return Result.success(output) so i can observe the value of output, that is calculate in background task

```
override fun doWork(): Result {

        try{
        //do something

            var x = doSomething()

        val output = Data.Builder()
                .putIntString("something",x )
                .build()

          return Result.success(output)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            return Result.failure()
        }

    }
```

If i use this code when i observe output is always null 
Any suggestions?

Comment: WorkManager already works in the background, so perform the calculation synchronously.

Comment: yes, but i receive the result before "dosometning()" finish... i need to check the status of this task

Comment: What is `doSomething` method actually

Comment: initialize LocationManager, find some positions and set the center. I need to return the center